# DEGRADED disk is back ONLINE after reboot

Tags: zfs, freenas

I had a degraded disk on a ZFS volume in my FreeNAS server [build 9.10.2-U1 (86c7ef5)] and before trying to replace it, I rebooted the server.

What does the following mean and do I have an issue with that disk?

- At startup, I get the following even though all disks are back online in volume status: [image: Alert]
- During the scrub operation, a new alert showed the disk in a degraded state, with 670 checksum (unsure what that means): [image: Degraded disk] [image: New Alert]
- Scrub results:

  ```
  The scrub operation is now finished. Here are the final results:

       state: DEGRADED
      status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
              attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.

      action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
              using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.

         see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-9P

        scan: scrub repaired 66.7M in 16h55m with 0 errors on Sat Jan  2 13:32:13 2021

      config:
        NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        storage                                         DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
            gptid/e0ef3f08-70b6-11e6-b8eb-1c98ec0f2cd4  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/e1b21671-70b6-11e6-b8eb-1c98ec0f2cd4  DEGRADED     0     0 1.29K  too many errors
            gptid/e2841c02-70b6-11e6-b8eb-1c98ec0f2cd4  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/e3717f0c-70b6-11e6-b8eb-1c98ec0f2cd4  ONLINE       0     0     0

      errors: No known data errors
  ```
- `smartctl -a`:

  ```
  SMART Error Log Version: 1
  No Errors Logged

  SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
  Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
  # 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     39365         172825824
  # 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     39365         172825825
  # 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     39364         -

  SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
   SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
      1        0        0  Not_testing
      2        0        0  Not_testing
      3        0        0  Not_testing
      4        0        0  Not_testing
      5        0        0  Not_testing

  Selective self-test flags (0x0):
    After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.

  If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
  ```

Comment: The SMART data is going to be critical here, and running a scrub was probably a good first instinct.

Comment: I have 4x3TB disks, used approximately at 60%. Which SMART test should I run? Long Self-Test, Short Self-Test, Conveyance Self-Test, Offline Immediate Test?

Comment: There's probably no need for the actual *tests*, but you should update this question with what the current smart *data* shows on the drive. I'm particularly interested in if it shows any pending/reallocated sectors.

Comment: What do you mean by "smart data"?

Comment: You should be able to go into a shell and run `smartctl -a` against the device. I don't think this is exposed in the FreeNAS GUI anywhere. This will show the drive's own health monitoring statistics.

Comment: What model disks do you have. Some disks have specific support for RAID - of your disks don't it could be related to an aggressive OS/controller and a disk that did not respond quite quickly enough - ie this.might not be a disk failure, rather using a disk in a way it was not meant to be used.

Comment: I have 3 Western Digital Red and 1 Western Digital Green. The one that was DEGRADED is a Red. The server is running for 4-5 years now, without any issue. So I guess it is expected to have to change one disk now.

Comment: @Karu: looks like no smart tests have ever been run on the disks. *SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]*

Comment: What exact model is the RED drive? (I'm at the edge of my knowledge here but -) These drives have a checkered reputation. While they are RAID compatible drives sold for use in NAS's there was something if a scandal in that WD silently started releasing models which use SMR technology which can be slower and cause issues in RAID arrays.  I wonder if your drive is affected? Its complicated - but https://www.extremetech.com/computing/311854-western-digital-sued-to-permanently-block-smr-in-nas-hdds may be useful in explaining/evidencing this if the drive is an SMR one.

Comment: Here are the results of the `smartctl -a against` the drive in error:
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4N4DF8222
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 20c931bcc
Firmware Version: 82.00A82. I don't know if it helps determining if it is using SMR?

Comment: According to this link (https://nascompares.com/answer/how-to-tell-a-difference-between-dm-smr-and-non-smr-cmr-drives-hdd-compare/), it looks like I am a lucky guy ! My disks are apparently using the CMR technology.

Comment: @Karu : the scrub operation has just finished. I edited the question with the result. Also, I finally get the result of a SMART short test: `# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     39364         -`. I ran a SMART long test for comparison purpose but I get this error: `Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     39365         172825825`.

Comment: @Karu: just edited the question with the output of the `smartctl -a` instruction

Comment: _(FYI: This really should be asked on the [TrueNAS forum](https://www.truenas.com/community/) [iXsystems integrated FreeNAS and TrueNAS], which is the best place for FreeNAS/TrueNAS issues)_. You either have a bad drive or a bad SATA cable, use a known-good SATA cable, boot, and if the issue is still present replace the drive. S.M.A.R.T will likely show hardware errors _(directly above test results)_, which the long test confirmed. Replace the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the output from `smartctl -a` has shown, the drive is reporting read errors from its onboard testing. This eliminates your raid controller or a software problem.

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     39365         172825824
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     39365         172825825
```

**This is very bad.** Source a new drive and replace it ASAP. The error is probably transient because it appears to be happening around the same physical location on the disk - FreeNAS/zfs probably didn't access that exact spot again until you issued a scrub and told it to check that whole volume, which is why the drive came back online on next boot.

Comment: Just an FYI, there is no RAID controller with ZFS, as it's software RAID.

Comment: @JW0914 There is a *disk controller*, though, whether or not it's a RAID controller or not.  And there very well could be a RAID controller in use here.

Comment: There is no hardware RAID controller involved if using ZFS... you don't do ZFS on top of hardware RAID - it's one or the other _(there are reasons for this, pointless being one of them, performance degradation being another; for a complete understanding, please see the TrueNAS [forum](https://www.truenas.com/community/))_. A disk controller is not the same as a hardware RAID controller... they're two completely different things.